# Migrate MS SQL Server database to MySQL using Workbench migration wizard over ssh

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssh, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a SQL Server 2008 database to MySQL. The MySQL database is on a vps on digital ocean. In the migration process, the source selection was successfull but the target selection is not. For the target selection, I used the connection method as Standard TCP/IP over SSH. Clicking on Test connection gives the error "Unsupported connection method. MySQL connections over SSH are not supported in this version of MySQL workbench migration wizard."
I have MySQL version 6.1
These are the parameters I used:

SSH Hostname: *host IP address*:22

SSH Username: root

SSH Password: *host password*

SSH KeyFile: *I did not set up a key file for my MySQL db. Is it required?*

MySQL HostName: 127.0.0.1

MySQL Server port: 3306

username: root

password: *password to MySQL*

Please tell me if I am missing something or if I am giving the parameters wrong. 
Do I have to set the ssh key file to migrate the database over ssh?

**Note**
**The migration process does not support source or target RDBMS connections through SSH.
A workaround is to set up an encrypted tunnel, and then treat the MySQL target as a standard TCP (unencrypted) connection.**

I found this note on the MySQL Workbech documentation for migration wizard. Heres the link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-install.html

I do not know how to do the migration with the suggested work around. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have the same problem here. Any solution would be great though. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did:

First, Install MySQL on the same machine where the MS SQL Server database exists. Use the MySQL Migration wizard to migrate the database locally. Now there are two options here.

OPTION 1: Create a backup file for the migrated database in MySQL. Use this backup file and restore database in the target MySQL.

OPTION 2: Export each table from the migrated database in MySQL to .csv files and then copy these files to the server and import them in to the target MySQL database.